# java.sql.SQLException:EXECUTE permission denied on object testproc, database mydatabase, owner dbo - Sybase ASE

Tags: java, sap-ase, sqlexception

Im using Sybase ASE DB.

I do like this:

```
  Create procedure testproc
As  
Begin   
  SELECT @line = 'drop table testtable'
        execute(@line)
end
```

This works fine if I execute this proc directly. But when I execute a

```
stmt= connection.prepareCall("{ call testproc }");
    stmt.execute();
```

Error:

```
throws 
java.sql.SQLException:EXECUTE permission denied on object testproc, database mydatabase, owner dbo
```

The same is working fine with a Sybase IQ DB. How to execute the same in ASE?

Comment: It is a problem of right. Use the same user that you used in your sql tool.

Comment: @davidhxxx I test with the same user (and also this user is alias of dbo)